# libcurl with c and infinite loop

Tags: c, linux, libcurl

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    while(1)
    {

        CURL *curl;
        CURLcode res;

        curl = curl_easy_init();

        if(curl) {

            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, \
                             "http://192.168.0.120/test.php?r=09210&o=919292" );

            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);

            res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);       

        }

        sleep(15);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

This program does not run continuously, it stops updating the database with the values after a few days or hours. Of course, I have tested it by removing the data in the database and checked if it was updating or not. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Try to run it in a debugger, and you will probably find that it crashes after a few days -- my guess would be a memory leak or some other exception

Comment: What happens exactly? What is the return value of `curl_easy_perform`? What is in the web server logs?

Comment: I ran across the same problem my solution was to replace curl with raw sockets. The program is running fine over a year a go no crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try to move the init and cleanup outside of the while loop, to avoid unnecessary operations which may fail.

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if(!curl) {
        return 1;
    }

    while(1)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, \
                             "http://192.168.0.120/test.php?r=09210&o=919292" );

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        sleep(15);

    }

   curl_easy_cleanup(curl);       
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is curl_easy_perform I don't think initialization can fail on a  normal PC